# nginx rewrite complex urls

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need some help to rewrite the following url and I didn't find the solution:

I need to rewrite the url:

http://ip_address/number/file

to:

http://ip_address/only_last_three(number)/file-number

where number is an integer from 1 to n

Example:

http://127.0.0.1/34/file -> http://127.0.0.1/34/file-34

http://127.0.0.1/123456/file -> http://127.0.0.1/456/file-123456

Thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: Possible solution: `rewrite "^/(\d*?)(\d{1,3})/(file)$" /$2/$3-$1$2 redirect;`

Comment: Please clarify what you you mean bu `rewrite` the URL. Internal or external redirect?